# Worked example of computation/identification of jet group $G_{k}^{n}$ for Lorenz system

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, jet-bundles

Start with, for example, the Lorenz system

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} &= \sigma (y - x), \\[6pt]
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} &= x (\rho - z) - y, \\[6pt]
\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}t} &= x y - \beta z.
\end{align}$$

- any references which have general techniques for (computing the jet groups)/(identifying which Lie groups they are) of this (or similar) system(s) (or)
- worked computation for this system

(the systems that I eventually want to apply this computation to are in Julien Clint Sprott's [Strange Attractors:
Creating Patterns in Chaos](http://sprott.physics.wisc.edu/sa.htm), ch6. p322)

Comment: Hi! can you clarify what is jet group in the context of dynamical systems, I cannot find a suitable source after web search? [a chat room for dynamical systems](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55403/dynamical-systems-and-chaos-theory)

Comment: The Lorenz system is a coupled triple of differential equations. To compute jets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_(mathematics), the jet group: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_group  At the end there are a bunch of jet groups $G_{k}^{n}$, which I need to know which Lie groups in particular they are, and I am unsure how to do that identification.